# SfdxError: No supported Android API package found

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

Im trying to setup a local android environment. Followed instructions here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.mobile_extensions_setup_android_studio, and here https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/set-up-your-salesforce-mobile-developer-tools-for-lightning-web-components

Everything is installed and working that is required by the instructions. I have installed, uninstalled, and reinstalled...and even followed the instructions on a new computer, but i keep getting the same problem when i try to verify setup via `sfdx force:lightning:local:setup -p Android` which is

```
  ✔ PASSED: Checking SDK root location (0.000 sec)
    › SDK root location is set to ANDROID_HOME:
    C:/Users/jamie/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
  ✔ PASSED: Checking Android SDK Prerequisites (0.110 sec)
    › Android SDK prerequisites are met.
  ✔ PASSED: Checking Android Command Line Tools (1.270 sec)
    › Android command line tools were detected at
    C:/Users/jamie/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/tools/bin
  ✔ PASSED: Checking SDK Platform Tools (0.023 sec)
    › Android Platform tools were detected at
    C:/Users/jamie/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools.
  ✖ FAILED: Checking SDK Platform API (1.278 sec)
    › SfdxError: No supported Android API package found. Minimum supported Android
    API package version is 23.
  ✖ FAILED: Checking SDK Platform Emulator Images (3.304 sec)
    › SfdxError: Install at least one of these emulator images:
    google_apis,default,google_apis_playstore
ERROR running force:lightning:local:setup:  Requirement verifications for platform %s failed.
```

Its the same error, over and over an over, and it wont budge, despite almost every api downloaded and installed.

Ive googled it and asked on the community forums to no avail. So i come here to ask for any advice on this that may point me in the right direction.

If no one can help, can i please ask what `sfdx force:lightning:local:setup -p Android` means.
How is this constructed in relation to the file name, its location, and whatever class and method its calling. Essentially,  i cant read this line and deconstruct it. Initially i thought the file was called sfdx at ...force/lightning/local/setup, but nope. My hope is that if i could look to see if its looking for the api's in the wrong location i could change it, but more than that i just want to be able to read and understand it for future reference. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem today and may have a solution.

**Suggested Solution**
I think you need to set up a Virtual Device (in the Android Studio -> Virtual Device Manager) and configure that Device to use the same API level (I chose Marshmallow which is API level 23, Android 6) make sure you have the SDK Platform API downloaded as well (using the SDK Manager).

Once you have done this then try rerunning the setup check.

**Background**
I was running the same setup check call

```
    sfdx force:lightning:local:setup -p Android
```

and getting the same error as you.

I looked in the repo here https://github.com/forcedotcom/lwc-dev-mobile-core which is where the code is that runs for the above sfdx command.
I searched for the error message "No supported Android API package found" and discovered that it is returned even when the API package is *found* but there is no emulator configured for that API version.

So I went into Android Studio and set up another emulator (NB: I already had an emulator set up for the API version 31, but that didn't seem to work, because I didn't have SDK Platform API version 31 downloaded).

I hope this helps! Let me know if you need more info.